# My custom method is not working properly

Tags: c#

i have a little problem. After clicking a button i want to buy thing.

```
private void btnBuyLemonade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BuyBuildings(lemonadeFactory, money, lemonadeFactoryPrice);
        }
```

then I have something like this method

```
private void BuyBuildings(int buildingName, double _money, double buildingNamePrice)
        {
            buildingName++;
            _money -= lemonadeFactoryPrice;
            buildingNamePrice *= 1.8;
        }
```

But its not working as you may know. What should I do/read to write it properly. Ofc I want to increase number of lemonadeFactory buildings of 1, multiple its price by 1.8 and minus lemonadeFactoryPrice from my money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in C#, primitive types (like `int`, `double`, etc) are passed by value. So when you operate on them inside your method it's actually changing a copy of those variables. If those are class-level variables, you can change them without passing them as parameters, like:

```
private void BuyBuildings()
        {
            buildingName++;
            _money -= lemonadeFactoryPrice;
            buildingNamePrice *= 1.8;
        }
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass the variables by reference : `private void BuyBuildings(ref int buildingName, ref double _money, ref double buildingNamePrice)`

Comment: Everything is passed by value by default.  It's just that for value types that means the value is copied vs with reference types where it's the reference that is copied and not the actual object the reference points to.

Comment: @juharr yes, of course. I didn't see any point to getting into those details in the scope of the question here. It's probably sufficient for this user to understand "primitives by value, complex by reference"; they will likely be looking up those terms anyhow.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Thanks for your help. I think this is it. I will now read about passing parameter :)